# Bootstrap accordion weird bounce in safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have made bootstrap accordion for my website. Everything works perfect except in Safari.

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong.

If you are running Safari you can see the problem [here](https://weltenbruecken.com/)

Also, the small piece of css code that I added to this accordion is:

```
.collapsing {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .35s;
    -o-transition-duration: .35s;
    transition-duration: .35s;
    -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
    -o-transition-property: height, visibility;
    transition-property: height, visibility;
}
```

The problem wasn't in above code because I tested accordion without it and still I had the same problem in Safari.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
  .collapse {
  -webkit-transition: height 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
   transition: height 0.35s ease;
   }
```

Comment: Still the same problem. 

Thank you anyway, but this doesn't help.

Comment: sorry for that does  you make  -webkit-transition: height 0s ease;  ?? because  its make a jerk on low time

Comment: i am using safari 5.1.7 ,when i disable the  transition it work toggle but a bit of jerk , actually  it happen late transition which show height open then close then again open

Comment: I solved it. Yesterday I added your css to a class .collapsing and not to .collapse :). That was my mistake. 

This works.

Thank you

Comment: Hey @Potta I have exactly the same problem but this solution is not working for me, does the fact that im loading a pdf on an iframe can affect the whole accordion behaviour ? Really need some light here guys.